# Azure Custom Domain - awverify not found

Tags: azure, dns

A couple of days ago I set up a new site in Azure and modified my DNS records to point to the site. I am unable to add the custom domains through the management tool or the portal.

The error I see is 
"A CNAME record pointing from mysite.com to mysite.azurewebsites.net was not found. Alternative record awverify.mysite.com to awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net was not found either."
(Changed my real domain to mysite as I'd rather not put that here).

The worst part is when I visit "mysite.com" it is showing me an Azure 404 page saying "The web site owner has registered a custom domain to point to the Microsoft Azure Web Site, but has not yet configured Azure to recognize it.".. I'm trying to configure it but Azure is not letting me!!!

For my DNS i have:

- an A-Record pointing to my virtual IP
- a second A-Record for www pointing to the IP (I did have www as a CNAME-Record for mysite.azurewebsites.net but that didn't seem to be working)
- a CNAME-Record for awverify.mysite.com to awverify.mysite.azurewebsites.net
- a CNAME-Record for awverify.www.mysite.com to awverify.www.mysite.azurewebsites.net

I thought maybe it was taking forever to propagate but it's been 2 days now.

Thanks!

Comment: Usually it takes around 5-10 minutes depending to DNS caching. Just in case, are you sure you are not hitting an old cached DNS entry.

Comment: Thanks, but it's been 2 days now since I updated the DNS settings. Is it possible that it could still be cached?

Comment: Honestly, I can't think of a cache that long but still, try running ipconfig -/flushdns. If you can share the domain I can test it on my end as well.

Comment: `ipconfig /flushdns` would not do anything since it will only `flush` the DNS entries you have locally on your own system, not in the Azure environment  from where the lookup is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it usually takes a couple of minutes for DNS records to be available, it can take up to 72 hours for DNS records to propagate. If it is all configured correctly (and looking at the list you posted, it is), it's a matter of waiting for it to propagate.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it was just a matter of waiting. I found it strange that I was able to see the DNS had changed when I used the http://www.digwebinterface.com/ site, but Azure didn't allow me to add the domains until over 2 days later. Maybe it hadn't propagated everywhere but I as far as I could see it had.